# glmmTMB with spatial autocorrelation structure still keeps spatial autocorrelation?

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, glmmtmb

I wonder if `glmmTMB` added `exp(coordinates + 0 | SITES )` as spatial autocorrelated structure is still keeping spatial autoCorrelated. What should I do next. And here is my formula with `glmmTMB`:

```
df$coordinates = numFactor(df$Longitude,df$Latitude) 
M <-  glmmTMB(lgDouYa ~ MFS*CD*SNC +  
                     I(MFS^2)+I(CD^2)+I(SNC^2)  +(1|SITES/YEAR) +
                exp(coordinates + 0 | SITES )   
              , ziformula=~1
              ,dispformula=~0
              ,  data = df
              )
```

And then, I tried to test spatial autocorrelation with `DHARMa`.

```
library(DHARMa)
recalculateResiduals(simulateResiduals(M,n = 1000), group = df$SITES) %>% 
  testSpatialAutocorrelation(x = aggregate(df$Latitude, list(df$SITES), mean)$x,
                             y = aggregate(df$Longitude, list(df$SITES), mean)$x)
```

But the result is significant for spatial autocorrelation.

```
DHARMa Moran's I test for spatial
    autocorrelation

data:  .
observed = -0.109366, expected =
-0.023810, sd = 0.036913, p-value =
0.02046
alternative hypothesis: Spatial autocorrelation
```

So what should I do to resolve the Spatial autocorrelation?
Thanks to everyone who pays attention to my question. Thank you.

Here is my dataset:

```
df <- 
structure(list(YEAR = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2017", "2018", "2019"
), class = "factor"), SITES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 
53L, 55L, 55L, 55L), .Label = c("CA1", "CA10", "CA11", "CA12", 
"CA13", "CA14", "CA15", "CA17", "CA18", "CA19", "CA2", "CA20", 
"CA3", "CA4", "CA5", "CA6", "CA7", "CA9", "CB1", "CB10", "CB11", 
"CB12", "CB13", "CB14", "CB15", "CB16", "CB17", "CB18", "CB19", 
"CB2", "CB20", "CB3", "CB4", "CB5", "CB6", "CB7", "CB8", "CB9", 
"CC1", "CC10", "CC11", "CC12", "CC13", "CC14", "CC15", "CC16", 
"CC17", "CC18", "CC2", "CC3", "CC4", "CC5", "CC6", "CC7", "CC8", 
"CC9", "CA16", "CA8"), class = "factor"), lgDouYa = c(0.869423773288886, 
0.0965586152896391, -0.647230897017041, 2.30836181466664, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.6906216295849, 0.348755695517045, -0.647230897017041, 
0.492483444930366, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.68000152309815, 
0.275129454289906, 0.376838393944666, 0.414754435392883, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.463010775531561, 1.0653594780622, 0.658075667360263, 
0.615141104595973, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.783103333893848, 
0.921779971361295, 0.0965586152896391, 0.18510477917444, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.16318304340856, 1.40225483961546, -0.647230897017041, 
1.27362258886383, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.948927783595636, 
-0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.573311845426998, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.76882503851871, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
0.433934970416483, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.702259280165173, 
-0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.275129454289906, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.0200762327862, 1.31410405776748, 0.532462663541631, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.783103333893848, 0.724870518877707, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.747858594763302, 0.573311845426998, 0.0965586152896391, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.819348843909036, 1.19837970230692, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.463010775531561, 0.18510477917444, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.18510477917444, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.0965586152896391, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.573311845426998, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.0200762327862, 0.895295078198926, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.275129454289906, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.85963585496984, -0.647230897017041, 0.0965586152896391, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.395725295814487, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.512370678114162, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.636461718809469, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.844121707593991, 1.50289108284423, 0.348755695517045, 
1.09680356209351, 1.96901778371413, -0.647230897017041, 0.976793633267482, 
1.12937124274826, -0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 0.18510477917444, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.55948717001655, 2.10876310243032, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 0.275129454289906, -0.647230897017041, 1.45073686181061, 
1.3568616481425, -0.647230897017041, 0.275129454289906, 2.69717709201565, 
-0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041, 1.23512706836797, -0.647230897017041, 
-0.647230897017041, 1.62157161294753, 0.0965586152896391, 0.275129454289906, 
-0.647230897017041, -0.647230897017041), DouYa = c(0.826666666666667, 
0.0133333333333333, 0, 13.56, 0, 0, 5.62666666666667, 0.0533333333333333, 
0, 0.186666666666667, 0, 0, 0.32, 0.04, 0.0666666666666667, 0.0933333333333333, 
0, 0, 0.12, 1.61333333333333, 0.293333333333333, 0.24, 0, 0, 
0.506666666666667, 1.17333333333333, 0.0133333333333333, 0.0266666666666667, 
0, 0, 1.86666666666667, 2.88, 0, 2.28, 0, 0, 1.18666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.226666666666667, 0, 0, 6.02666666666667, 0, 0, 0.106666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.346666666666667, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 1.50666666666667, 
2.36, 0.213333333333333, 0, 0.506666666666667, 0.4, 0, 0, 0.453333333333333, 
0.226666666666667, 0.0133333333333333, 0, 0.533333333333333, 
1.93333333333333, 0, 0, 0.12, 0.0266666666666667, 0, 0, 0.0266666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0133333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.226666666666667, 0, 
0, 1.50666666666667, 0.84, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 7.34666666666667, 
0, 0.0133333333333333, 0, 0.08, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.28, 
0, 0, 0, 0.8, 4, 0.0533333333333333, 1.64, 7.68, 0, 1.24, 1.78666666666667, 
0, 0, 0.0266666666666667, 0, 4.96, 8.77333333333333, 0, 0, 0.04, 
0, 2.92, 2.6, 0, 0.04, 14.2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5.08, 0.0133333333333333, 
0.04, 0, 0), MFS = structure(c(-0.704470454018713, -0.704470454018713, 
-0.704470454018713, -0.49219727458324, -0.49219727458324, -0.49219727458324, 
0.527968407082596, 0.527968407082596, 0.527968407082596, 2.61289211033616, 
2.61289211033616, 2.61289211033616, 0.973964696600823, 0.973964696600823, 
0.973964696600823, 0.810053831748292, 0.810053831748292, 0.810053831748292, 
-0.646038990797124, -0.646038990797124, -0.646038990797124, -0.0405740424844551, 
-0.0405740424844551, -0.0405740424844551, -0.608003192334688, 
-0.608003192334688, -0.608003192334688, 0.365588661218839, 0.365588661218839, 
0.365588661218839, 1.27085722552215, 1.27085722552215, 1.27085722552215, 
-0.348247043875247, -0.348247043875247, -0.348247043875247, -1.34256604272275, 
-1.34256604272275, -1.34256604272275, -0.442366256663233, -0.442366256663233, 
-0.442366256663233, 0.590527862041596, 0.590527862041596, 0.590527862041596, 
0.425429474000678, 0.425429474000678, 0.425429474000678, 0.867288135599791, 
0.867288135599791, 0.867288135599791, 2.45848921736224, 2.45848921736224, 
2.45848921736224, -0.316682761074777, -0.316682761074777, -0.316682761074777, 
-0.316682761074777, 1.27997422497702, 1.27997422497702, 1.27997422497702, 
1.27997422497702, 0.929231872203228, 0.929231872203228, 0.929231872203228, 
0.929231872203228, 0.810280534910473, 0.810280534910473, 0.810280534910473, 
0.810280534910473, 0.708521487075458, 0.708521487075458, 0.708521487075458, 
0.708521487075458, 1.74376310922201, 1.74376310922201, 1.74376310922201, 
1.74376310922201, -0.638866315394154, -0.638866315394154, -0.638866315394154, 
-0.638866315394154, -1.04054218648781, -1.04054218648781, -1.04054218648781, 
-1.04054218648781, -0.910039293047068, -0.910039293047068, -0.910039293047068, 
-0.910039293047068, -0.376862291489762, -0.376862291489762, -0.376862291489762, 
-0.376862291489762, -0.92230815650878, -0.92230815650878, -0.92230815650878, 
-0.92230815650878, -1.38047124297597, -1.38047124297597, -1.38047124297597, 
-1.38047124297597, -0.674768565361297, -0.674768565361297, -0.674768565361297, 
-0.674768565361297, -0.673581308608378, -0.673581308608378, -0.673581308608378, 
-0.673581308608378, -0.595112731354483, -0.595112731354483, -0.595112731354483, 
-1.2473400909545, -1.2473400909545, -1.2473400909545, -1.14108242285356, 
-1.14108242285356, -1.14108242285356, -1.06398632494527, -1.06398632494527, 
-1.06398632494527, -1.09717275254042, -1.09717275254042, -1.09717275254042, 
0.23200886760946, 0.23200886760946, 0.23200886760946, 0.199500012511306, 
0.199500012511306, 0.199500012511306, -0.930127869136063, -0.930127869136063, 
-0.930127869136063, -1.39138211207404, -1.39138211207404, -1.39138211207404, 
0.340576705522566, 0.340576705522566, 0.340576705522566, 1.41673194858262, 
1.41673194858262, 1.41673194858262), "`scaled:center`" = 0.531172306358715, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.1321853801893, .Dim = c(143L, 
1L)), CD = structure(c(0.571325446748364, 0.571325446748364, 
0.571325446748364, 0.0487947267179488, 0.0487947267179488, 0.0487947267179488, 
-1.20061533945842, -1.20061533945842, -1.20061533945842, -1.65920875929318, 
-1.65920875929318, -1.65920875929318, 0.0776291954336383, 0.0776291954336383, 
0.0776291954336383, -1.24474461331896, -1.24474461331896, -1.24474461331896, 
-0.423839825708794, -0.423839825708794, -0.423839825708794, -0.398515640141102, 
-0.398515640141102, -0.398515640141102, 1.34634581892399, 1.34634581892399, 
1.34634581892399, 0.413111970577926, 0.413111970577926, 0.413111970577926, 
0.353938626083119, 0.353938626083119, 0.353938626083119, 0.856661319778408, 
0.856661319778408, 0.856661319778408, 1.39047509278453, 1.39047509278453, 
1.39047509278453, 1.20016759926097, 1.20016759926097, 1.20016759926097, 
0.478302943326443, 0.478302943326443, 0.478302943326443, -0.172353111605864, 
-0.172353111605864, -0.172353111605864, -0.0244197503688467, 
-0.0244197503688467, -0.0244197503688467, -0.767596839701932, 
-0.767596839701932, -0.767596839701932, -0.454680170509054, -0.454680170509054, 
-0.454680170509054, -0.454680170509054, -1.04390627035141, -1.04390627035141, 
-1.04390627035141, -1.04390627035141, -0.0161455115199964, -0.0161455115199964, 
-0.0161455115199964, -0.0161455115199964, 1.04370926466454, 1.04370926466454, 
1.04370926466454, 1.04370926466454, 0.579850420107785, 0.579850420107785, 
0.579850420107785, 0.579850420107785, -1.08126571242652, -1.08126571242652, 
-1.08126571242652, -1.08126571242652, 1.39523904848538, 1.39523904848538, 
1.39523904848538, 1.39523904848538, 0.810526169833304, 0.810526169833304, 
0.810526169833304, 0.810526169833304, 0.659834728980003, 0.659834728980003, 
0.659834728980003, 0.659834728980003, -0.139256156210463, -0.139256156210463, 
-0.139256156210463, -0.139256156210463, -0.786652662505345, -0.786652662505345, 
-0.786652662505345, -0.786652662505345, 0.0738681777750704, 0.0738681777750704, 
0.0738681777750704, 0.0738681777750704, -0.313015172036317, -0.313015172036317, 
-0.313015172036317, -0.313015172036317, -0.789410742121628, -0.789410742121628, 
-0.789410742121628, -0.789410742121628, 1.39298243789024, 1.39298243789024, 
1.39298243789024, 0.301785847884306, 0.301785847884306, 0.301785847884306, 
-1.60780818462608, -1.60780818462608, -1.60780818462608, 0.198733964039536, 
0.198733964039536, 0.198733964039536, 0.41185829802507, 0.41185829802507, 
0.41185829802507, -1.20613149869099, -1.20613149869099, -1.20613149869099, 
0.349425404892837, 0.349425404892837, 0.349425404892837, 0.42213841295849, 
0.42213841295849, 0.42213841295849, 1.56247896703638, 1.56247896703638, 
1.56247896703638, -0.381214958911687, -0.381214958911687, -0.381214958911687, 
-0.561994541033535, -0.561994541033535, -0.561994541033535), "`scaled:center`" = 1.67953928571429, "`scaled:scale`" = 0.398828225808178, .Dim = c(143L, 
1L)), SNC = structure(c(0.248739188017824, 0.248739188017824, 
0.248739188017824, -0.156470857543067, -0.156470857543067, -0.156470857543067, 
0.00417693903715141, 0.00417693903715141, 0.00417693903715141, 
2.88764474556734, 2.88764474556734, 2.88764474556734, -0.308032697947342, 
-0.308032697947342, -0.308032697947342, 0.692282191545496, 0.692282191545496, 
0.692282191545496, 0.0974639176599148, 0.0974639176599148, 0.0974639176599148, 
-1.05547480711491, -1.05547480711491, -1.05547480711491, -0.426908696004394, 
-0.426908696004394, -0.426908696004394, -0.83090503313362, -0.83090503313362, 
-0.83090503313362, -1.21694859971112, -1.21694859971112, -1.21694859971112, 
-1.10457942741272, -1.10457942741272, -1.10457942741272, -0.848183521223307, 
-0.848183521223307, -0.848183521223307, -0.31204467859646, -0.31204467859646, 
-0.31204467859646, -0.885285913696871, -0.885285913696871, -0.885285913696871, 
-0.448637448343523, -0.448637448343523, -0.448637448343523, -0.496696930825182, 
-0.496696930825182, -0.496696930825182, -0.458937112951132, -0.458937112951132, 
-0.458937112951132, -0.593203608204169, -0.593203608204169, -0.593203608204169, 
-0.593203608204169, 4.07313445619698, 4.07313445619698, 4.07313445619698, 
4.07313445619698, -0.554988649668245, -0.554988649668245, -0.554988649668245, 
-0.554988649668245, -0.717507580080615, -0.717507580080615, -0.717507580080615, 
-0.717507580080615, 0.0712680440097931, 0.0712680440097931, 0.0712680440097931, 
0.0712680440097931, -0.0862443391219557, -0.0862443391219557, 
-0.0862443391219557, -0.0862443391219557, -0.825139918083207, 
-0.825139918083207, -0.825139918083207, -0.825139918083207, -0.448283450050954, 
-0.448283450050954, -0.448283450050954, -0.448283450050954, 1.28526304572203, 
1.28526304572203, 1.28526304572203, 1.28526304572203, 0.340829315270473, 
0.340829315270473, 0.340829315270473, 0.340829315270473, -0.26578890170075, 
-0.26578890170075, -0.26578890170075, -0.26578890170075, 0.241389509181626, 
0.241389509181626, 0.241389509181626, 0.241389509181626, -0.280488259373148, 
-0.280488259373148, -0.280488259373148, -0.280488259373148, 1.74291540976782, 
1.74291540976782, 1.74291540976782, 1.74291540976782, 0.544833474159644, 
0.544833474159644, 0.544833474159644, -0.179025605898191, -0.179025605898191, 
-0.179025605898191, 1.64495902509545, 1.64495902509545, 1.64495902509545, 
-0.530107626819095, -0.530107626819095, -0.530107626819095, 0.225392157769807, 
0.225392157769807, 0.225392157769807, 0.579339879154367, 0.579339879154367, 
0.579339879154367, -0.440006632829455, -0.440006632829455, -0.440006632829455, 
-0.135416387665974, -0.135416387665974, -0.135416387665974, -0.762600219729313, 
-0.762600219729313, -0.762600219729313, -0.0303126088960203, 
-0.0303126088960203, -0.0303126088960203, -0.4224078605703, -0.4224078605703, 
-0.4224078605703), "`scaled:center`" = 16.3174214285714, "`scaled:scale`" = 5.93223200247334, .Dim = c(143L, 
1L)), Latitude = c(41.05686278, 41.05686278, 41.05686278, 41.11095806, 
41.11095806, 41.11095806, 41.04523861, 41.04523861, 41.04523861, 
40.95670806, 40.95670806, 40.95670806, 40.99668806, 40.99668806, 
40.99668806, 41.04156694, 41.04156694, 41.04156694, 41.09246028, 
41.09246028, 41.09246028, 40.99216861, 40.99216861, 40.99216861, 
41.03523028, 41.03523028, 41.03523028, 41.02716667, 41.02716667, 
41.02716667, 41.01156083, 41.01156083, 41.01156083, 41.06100694, 
41.06100694, 41.06100694, 40.94746417, 40.94746417, 40.94746417, 
40.900705, 40.900705, 40.900705, 40.87212056, 40.87212056, 40.87212056, 
40.90833583, 40.90833583, 40.90833583, 40.82387833, 40.82387833, 
40.82387833, 40.99983361, 40.99983361, 40.99983361, 41.17633167, 
41.17633167, 41.17633167, 41.17633167, 40.80911056, 40.80911056, 
40.80911056, 40.80911056, 40.80239444, 40.80239444, 40.80239444, 
40.80239444, 40.82870833, 40.82870833, 40.82870833, 40.82870833, 
41.02167088, 41.02167088, 41.02167088, 41.02167088, 40.98107699, 
40.98107699, 40.98107699, 40.98107699, 40.98334098, 40.98334098, 
40.98334098, 40.98334098, 40.99086151, 40.99086151, 40.99086151, 
40.99086151, 41.16152528, 41.16152528, 41.16152528, 41.16152528, 
41.16686889, 41.16686889, 41.16686889, 41.16686889, 41.07348806, 
41.07348806, 41.07348806, 41.07348806, 41.03278333, 41.03278333, 
41.03278333, 41.03278333, 40.97858194, 40.97858194, 40.97858194, 
40.97858194, 41.03570917, 41.03570917, 41.03570917, 41.03570917, 
41.021529, 41.021529, 41.021529, 41.016319, 41.016319, 41.016319, 
41.045005, 41.045005, 41.045005, 41.083288, 41.083288, 41.083288, 
41.129119, 41.129119, 41.129119, 41.172374, 41.172374, 41.172374, 
40.998956, 40.998956, 40.998956, 40.970129, 40.970129, 40.970129, 
40.886755, 40.886755, 40.886755, 40.85327, 40.85327, 40.85327, 
40.829648, 40.829648, 40.829648), Longitude = c(80.34026694, 
80.34026694, 80.34026694, 80.46016028, 80.46016028, 80.46016028, 
80.48630833, 80.48630833, 80.48630833, 80.50068278, 80.50068278, 
80.50068278, 80.56087556, 80.56087556, 80.56087556, 80.54815722, 
80.54815722, 80.54815722, 80.53416472, 80.53416472, 80.53416472, 
80.29715028, 80.29715028, 80.29715028, 80.242545, 80.242545, 
80.242545, 80.205635, 80.205635, 80.205635, 80.32743694, 80.32743694, 
80.32743694, 80.21906472, 80.21906472, 80.21906472, 80.34813583, 
80.34813583, 80.34813583, 80.3566375, 80.3566375, 80.3566375, 
80.42242306, 80.42242306, 80.42242306, 80.41108333, 80.41108333, 
80.41108333, 80.46019611, 80.46019611, 80.46019611, 80.3918025, 
80.3918025, 80.3918025, 80.41081194, 80.41081194, 80.41081194, 
80.41081194, 80.56281944, 80.56281944, 80.56281944, 80.56281944, 
80.46875, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.46875, 80.41125278, 80.41125278, 
80.41125278, 80.41125278, 80.35851237, 80.35851237, 80.35851237, 
80.35851237, 80.39885327, 80.39885327, 80.39885327, 80.39885327, 
80.33922402, 80.33922402, 80.33922402, 80.33922402, 80.26167842, 
80.26167842, 80.26167842, 80.26167842, 80.47888889, 80.47888889, 
80.47888889, 80.47888889, 80.52739444, 80.52739444, 80.52739444, 
80.52739444, 80.53371111, 80.53371111, 80.53371111, 80.53371111, 
80.557725, 80.557725, 80.557725, 80.557725, 80.57384333, 80.57384333, 
80.57384333, 80.57384333, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.48125, 80.48125, 
80.349776, 80.349776, 80.349776, 80.551031, 80.551031, 80.551031, 
80.520748, 80.520748, 80.520748, 80.507795, 80.507795, 80.507795, 
80.484277, 80.484277, 80.484277, 80.406286, 80.406286, 80.406286, 
80.327168, 80.327168, 80.327168, 80.373821, 80.373821, 80.373821, 
80.387362, 80.387362, 80.387362, 80.434011, 80.434011, 80.434011, 
80.497346, 80.497346, 80.497346)), row.names = c(NA, -143L), class = "data.frame")
```